# Image half transparent

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make image half transparet ? I meant something like this `background:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(44, 44, 44),rgb(29, 38, 51,0.322));`

Comment: Do you mean reducing opacity ? by meaning half transparent ?

Comment: can you share the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a webkit solution available like below example. More information available here https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom,color-stop(0.00,  rgba(0,0,0,1)),color-stop(0.35,  rgba(0,0,0,1)),color-stop(0.50,  rgba(0,0,0,0)),color-stop(0.65,  rgba(0,0,0,0)),color-stop(1.00,  rgba(0,0,0,0)));
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" alt="" />
```